# Vuetify :: Динамическая смена схемы темы (dark -> light) и обратно

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Как можно сделать переключатель схемы темы [как здесь](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/ru/examples/layouts/sandbox)?

`app.$vuetify.dark = true` не дает никакого результата, работает

```
<v-app id="app" v-bind:class="'theme--'+sheme">
```

Может есть другие способы?
Добавить метку Vuetify не хватает репутации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Посмотрев на исходный код](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetifyjs.com/src/examples/layouts/sandbox.vue) указанного [примера](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/examples/layouts/sandbox), можно обнаружить ещё один способ, в котором устанавливается значение атрибута `dark` главного компонента:

```
<v-app :dark="dark">
    ...
</v-app>
```

В коде компонента:

```
data: () => ({
  dark: true,
}),
...
```

И в нужном месте устанавливаем свойство `dark` в `true` или `false`.

Comment: Да, так лучше всего, спасибо